# How to suppress a call to a dll to open warning dialog box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dialog

I am calling a function in an external dll to a device that runs some firmware. When I call device_open(), the device driver brings up a Warning dialog box that says there is a newer version of the firmware available. How do I suppress the warning dialog box? I am calling this function during an overnight test, so the dialog box prevents my tests from finishing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case scenario, I doubt that, writing code to resolve this problem, really worth the effort required (API to FindWindow, KeyStroke to send to the dialog, etc).
I suggest this free utility that runs keyboard macro [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). (I'm not linked to them)
Search, in particular, for the WinWaitActive macro

Pay attention to the [Run as Administrator](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-run-as-administrator-for-autohotkey-scripts-in-windows-vista/) problem for this kind of utility in Windows 7 or Vista